# How to create dynamic select option chantiers ouvrages in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have two selects, the 1st filled by ouvrages and other by chantiers there is between them belongsTo relation, I want when I choose chantier in 1st select the 2nd filled by ouvrages corresponds, but in my case it gives me empty data.

**mois.blade.php**

```
//select chantiers
<select class="form-control" id="chantier_id">
  <option selected disabled>Select Location</option>
    @foreach($chantiers as $chantier)
  <option value="{{ $chantier->id }}">{{ $chantier->chantier}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
//select ouvrages
<select class="form-control" id="ouvrage_id">
   <option value="0" selected disabled>- Select -</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
                                  });
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#chantier_id").change(function(){
                var chantier = $(this).val(); 

                $.ajax({
                    url: "{{ route('salarie.select') }}",  
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {
                          chantier:chantier,
                          "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"
                           },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success:function(response){
                       console.log(response);
                        var len = response.length;
                        $("#ouvrage_id").empty();
                        for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
                            var id = response[i]['id'];
                            var ouvrage = response[i]['ouvrage'];
                            $("#ouvrage_id").append("<option value='"+id+"'>"+ouvrage+"</option>");
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**SalarieController.php**

```
  public function select(request $request){
      $ouvrages = Ouvrage::where('chantier_id',$request->chantier_id);
        return response()->json(['options'=>$ouvrages]);
    }
```

**web.php**

```
Route::post('/select','SalarieController@select')->name('salarie.select'); 
Route::get('/mois','SalarieController@mois');
```

Comment: are you sure there is data in return? and also i guess you need  JSON.parse(response) because of json return

Comment: and for loop , you should use $.each() which will loop through response, you dont need iterator i then

Answer (score 0):

You need jQuery.parse(response) to parse json

and change loop to $.each to make it easy and less complex.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#example').DataTable();

        $("#chantier_id").change(function(){
            var chantier = $(this).val(); 

            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ route('salarie.select') }}",  
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                      chantier:chantier,
                      "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"
                       },
                dataType: 'json',
                success:function(response){
                   console.log(jQuery.parse(response));
                    $("#ouvrage_id").empty();
                    $.each( jQuery.parse(response), function( key, value ) {
                      $("#ouvrage_id").append("<option value='"+key+"'>"+value+"</option>");
                     });

                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thx for answer but its give me this error  SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Comment: i fixed it, use jQuery.parse

Comment: jQuery.parse is not a function lool

Comment: either you are using old jquery version, or its already parsed. try without it, just use response in the loop

Comment: Suny  ouvrage  select give me [Object Object]

Comment: its because it contains more then one field, your can use it like value.column_name or value['column_name']  in the loop, column name is the feld you want to display in option, and can also use this for option value